# Swift editing plist array

Tags: arrays, swift, plist

Hello Plain and simple I am trying to read a plist array, edit one value, and save it back.
I have tried a bunch of different methods, but can not seem to quite figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
//These three lines are outside any function to make them global
var dict: NSDictionary!
var data: NSMutableDictionary!
var path: String!

    let seconds = Float(mytime)

    var HighScores = dict.valueForKey("TiltHighScores") as? NSArray
    var myHighScores:NSArray = HighScores!
    var fakeLevelHighScore = myHighScores[MyGame.level] as NSNumber
    var LevelHighScore = fakeLevelHighScore.floatValue
    println("\(LevelHighScore)")
    println("\(seconds)")

    myNewHighScore = myHighScores


    if (seconds>=LevelHighScore){
        println("its happening")
        myNewHighScore[MyGame.level] = NSNumber(double: Double(seconds))
        //error one on line above, error two on line below
        data.setObject(myNewHighScores, forKey: "TiltHighScores")
         data.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
    }
```

Edit:
Sorry on how vague the question was here are some more details. I am able to read from the plist just fine. So the path and all that goes along with reading the plist is correct. I am having trouble editing and resaving an array. The array Im trying to edit is called TiltHighScores. I pull this into the variable HighScores. To unwrap it I set myHighScores to HighScores with the ! mark. I do the same process to pull a value out of the array getting the current level's highscore. This all works. From here on is where I am receiving the issues. I want to test and see if the users score (seconds) is greater than the level's highscore and if it is I want to save the new highscore. I tried doing this by creating an array (myNewHighscores) and filling its values with that of the original highscores and then changing the one value (the levels value) and resaving.

I am now receiving two errors in the if statement. See the comment for the exact lines
The first:
Cannot assign to the result of this expression
The second:
Use of unresolved identifier 'myNewHighScores'

I am pretty sure the first is causing the second.

If anyone can fix my logic I would be very grateful. If this is just a bad way of trying to accomplish my goal I am also open to a new way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to say for sure without more detail (for example, did you try running the debugger? What did it show?) but here's a possible scenario: `MyProperties.plist` does not already exist in the document directory. As a result:

1. `data` is nil, because there's nothing to read at `path`.
2. You copy a file to `path`, but that doesn't change `data`.
3. Later on you try to write `data` to `path`, but since `data` is nil nothing happens.

Other things that could cause the code to fail that might or might not be relevant depending on what else is going on with your project:

- Maybe `MyProperties.plist` doesn't exist in the app bundle, so it never gets copied.
- Maybe `MyProperties.plist` exists but its contents are not a valid `NSDictionary`.
- Maybe `MyProperties.plist` exists and is a valid `NSDictionary` but does not contain a value for `TiltHighScores`.
- Maybe `seconds` is less than or equal to `LevelHighScore`, so you never attempt to write `data` to a file.

There are some other weird things going on-- like the way you create `myNewHighScore`, assign values to it, and then never do anything with it. Was `myNewHighScore` supposed to be used somewhere?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried clearing things up and making my code more readable  in the edit.